# django_nose unit tests fail (no such option)

Tags: django, unit-testing, nose, nosetests

I have a new project and can't get django_nose set up correctly.  I have never had this problem before.  So, makes me think that it's a configuration issue.  But, I can't spot it.

I'm using virtualenv and have both nose and django-nose installed.  Here is my requirements.txt

```
Django==1.3.1
distribute==0.6.24
django-nose==1.0
nose==1.1.2
psycopg2==2.4.5
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django_nose',
    'main',
)

TEST_RUNNER = 'django_nose.NoseTestSuiteRunner'

NOSE_ARGS = [
    '--with-spec', '--spec-color',
    # Packages to test
    'main',
]
```

With my virtualenv activated, when I run:

```
python manage.py test
```

I get the following:

```
nosetests --verbosity 1 --with-spec --spec-color main
Usage: manage.py [options]

manage.py: error: no such option: --with-spec
```

Has anybody had this problem?  Can someone see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out.  My fault (as usual).  Just for future reference... those are actually not nose arguments and probably shouldn't be in there.  They are args for pinocchio.

[pinocchio](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pinocchio/0.3.1)

Comment: FYI - If a person has pinocchio installed in their virtualenv, then the --with-spec and --spec-color options in NOSE_ARGS will work fine.